# How do I use SELECT and WHERE by Django ORM?

Tags: django

So what I'm trying to do in SQL is this:

```
FROM TABLE
SELECT question
WHERE number === 3 AND type === "text"
```

Obviously, I have to columns-`question` and `number` and `type`. How do I write this in Django?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will return  list of dictionaries not ORM objects

```
TABLE.objects.filter(number=3,type="text").values("question", "number", "type")
```